# Lagrange theorem in group theory

Tags: group-theory

I studied group theory recently and met a problem in an exercise. The question is from Mathematical method for physics and engineering by Riley, Hobson and Bence. The problem is the sixth one in the chapter 28.

Prove that the set $\mathcal{M}$ of matrices:

$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
0&c
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where a,b,c are integers (mod 5) and $a\neq 0\neq c,$ form a non-Abelian group under matrix multiplication.

Show that the subset containing elements of $\mathcal{M}$ that are of order 1 or 2 do not form a proper subgroup of $\mathcal{M},$

(a) using Lagrange's theorem

(b) by direct demonstration that the set is not closed.

$\textbf{My Attempts}$

Non-Abelian group:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1&b_1\\
0&c_1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_2&b_2\\
0&c_2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1a_2&a_1b_2+b_1c_2\\
0&c_1c_2
\end{pmatrix}
\neq
\begin{pmatrix}
a_2&b_2\\
0&c_2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1&b_1\\
0&c_1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_2a_1&a_2b_1+b_2c_1\\
0&c_2c_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So this set is not an Abelian group. Then, I continue doing the next one. For order 1, the only element is identity. So that is not the proper subgroup but the trivial subgroup. However, for order 2, if I had:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
4&0\\
0&4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then this is the valid subgroup of order 2. It seems to contradict with the question. Then I got stuck here. I do not know if I was right or wrong.

Note: I use the following multiplication table for elements

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
&0&1&2&3&4\\
\hline
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&2&3&4\\
2&0&2&4&1&3\\
3&0&3&1&4&2\\
4&0&4&3&2&1
\end{array}
$$

example: $2\cdot 4=8.$ 8 mod 5 is 3.

Comment: There are other elements of order $2$, for instance $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 4\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: To show this is a nonabelian group, you need to do more than just show that the expressions you get do not appear to be equal. First, you need to show it is a **group**, which you have not done. Second, just because two expressions look different doesn't mean they evaluate to different things. For instance, the expression $x^5+1$ and the expression $x+1$ look different, but for every $x$ that is an integer modulo $5$, you will find that they give the same *value*. So your calculation is insufficient to establish non-abelianness. It would be better to give explicit values. (cont)

Comment: (cont) You also seem to misunderstand the second part of the question. The question asks you to show that the collection of **all** elements that have order $1$ or $2$ do not form a subgroup. (Compare with the collection of all elements of order $1$ or $2$ in an *abelian* group, which *do* form a subgroup). So you should determine what elements have order $1$ or $2$ in this group (after you prove it is a group). Presumably, the number of such elements will not be a divisor of the order of the group, and so that subset cannot be a subgroup.

Comment: To give you a stronger hint, the element $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&4\end{array}\right)$ also has order $2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you so much for your comment and correction! Yes I knew I misunderstood the question after you pointed out. Also thanks for Derek Holt and Frank